# Bash command substitution with extra whitespace: How to solve this?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to substitute the number of some process to find out its commandline as follows:

```
> cat /proc/"`fuser /dev/ttyS0`"/cmdline
cat: /proc/5231 /cmdline: No such file or directory
```

but it looks like `fuser` adds an extra whitespace to the PID. Any idea how to get this right, or solve otherwise?

Expected behavior: I want to get a process ID using `fuser` and in a second step display `/proc/<id>/cmdline`.

Comment: If your only problem is having extra whitespace, could you just pass it through a `sed` substitution that strips whitespace?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854655/command-to-escape-a-string-in-bash

Comment: But on my Debian Squeeze, `fuser /dev/tty1` outputs `/dev/tty1:            1038` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `` echo \"`fuser /dev/ttyS0`\" `` will show you that there is a leading space. If you split your operation in two steps, you could do the following

```
u=`fuser /dev/ttyS0`
cat /proc/${u// /}/cmdline
```

So first you assign the result of `fuser` to the variable `u` (which will still contain the space), and then you delete all spaces in `u` (starting a pattern substitution with `//` replaces all occurrences of patterns, if you only use `/` just the first occurrence will be replaces -- which would not be a problem in your example).

Comment: Or just like this: `u=( $( fuser /dev/ttyS0 ) ); cat /proc/$u/cmdline`

Comment: `arr=()` is defining an indexed array. It'll ignore leading/trailing unquoted white spaces. And `$arr` w/o a subscript is the same as `${arr[0]}`.