# Print a string with its special characters printed as literal escape sequences

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string in a shell/bash script. I want to print the string with all its "special characters" (eg. newlines, tabs, etc.) printed as literal escape sequences (eg. a newline is printed as `\n`, a tab is printed as `\t`, and so on).

(Not sure if I'm using the correct terminology; the example should hopefully clarify things.)

## Example

The desired output of...

```
a="foo\t\tbar"
b="foo      bar"

print_escape_seq "$a"
print_escape_seq "$b"
```

...is:

```
foo\t\tbar
foo\t\tbar
```

1. `$a` and `$b` are strings that were read in from a text file.
2. There are two tab characters between `foo` and `bar` in the `$b` variable.

## An attempt

This is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

print_escape_seq() {
  str=$(printf "%q\n" $1)
  str=${str/\/\//\/}
  echo $str
}

a="foo\t\tbar"
b="foo      bar"

print_escape_seq "$a"
print_escape_seq "$b"
```

The output is:

```
foo\t\tbar
foo bar
```

So, it doesn't work for `$b`.

Is there an entirely straightforward way to accomplish this that I've missed completely?

Comment: are you looking to visualize the `\t` and `\n` chars, or would you take this output and then use it, expecting that `\t,\n` (etc), would work as usual? Good luck.

Comment: Yes, to visualise the `\t` and `\n` characters. The output is just for display on `stdout`.

Comment: A good answer below, but maybe you should get comfortable reading the output of the shell debug/trace feature `set -vx; cmd1; cmd2 ... ; set +vx`. It will visualize your strings "for free". ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a search and replace pattern for each binary value you wish to replace. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

esc() {
    # space char after //
    v=${1// /\\s}   
    # tab character after //
    v=${v// /\\t}
    echo $v
}
esc "hello world"
esc "hello  world"
```

This outputs

```
hello\sworld
hello\tworld
```

Comment: Queastion says "ALL its special characters", so this should not really be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Bash has a string quoting operation ${var@Q}

Here is some example code

```sh
bash_encode () {
  esc=${1@Q}
  echo "${esc:2:-1}" 
}

testval=$(printf "hello\t\tworld")
set | grep "^testval="
echo "The encoded value of testval is" $(bash_encode "$testval")
```

Here is the output

```
testval=$'hello\t\tworld'
The encoded value of testval is hello\t\tworld
```

Comment: This works well for unknown special characters. For example I found a carriage return `\r`.

Comment: Btw, this does not work for length zero, due to the substring implementation that removes the surrounding `$'....'` part of the quoting.

`testval=""; $(bash_encode "$testval")`
return `substring expression < 0`

Comment: This doesn't work in zsh (or sh).  If you get a bad subsitution error, try `/bin/bash` to get back to a bash shell

Answer (score 0):

I required something similar for file paths, and I realized that ls -1b does the work, but in the research I found this solution in stackoverflow which is closer   to what you were requiring.
[Command to escape a string in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854655/command-to-escape-a-string-in-bash)

just compile it with  gcc -o "escapify" escapify.c