# How to create a list and append values in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm having a while loop and need to append the outcome of the loop to the list(like in python) in bash script. How to do that. I created an array but there are no commas in it. It has only space but I want commas so that I can use them in the .env file

```
arr=()
while [ ]
do 
  ........
  ........
  ........
  val='some value'
  arr+=$val
done

echo ${arr}
```

output:

```
('some value1' 'some value2' 'some value3')
```

Expected Outcome:

```
['some value1','some value2','some value3']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here one idea/approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=()

while IFS= read -r val; do
  arr+=("'$val'")
done < <(printf '%s\n' 'foo bar' 'baz more' 'qux lux')

(IFS=,; printf '[%s]' "${arr[*]}")
```

---

Output

```
['foo bar','baz more','qux lux']
```

Comment: In last line, you may remove `()` and `;` : `IFS=, printf...`

Comment: @EdouardThiel, thank you for that wonderful comment. but have you tried what you suggested though?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `echo` :

```sh
arr=()
while [ ... ]
do 
  ........
  ........
  ........
  val='some value'
  arr+=("$val")              # () and "" added
done

# print each value protected by "" and separated by ,
first=true
echo -n "arr values = [ "
for v in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    if $first ; then first=false ; else echo -n ", " ; fi
    echo -n "\"$v\""
done
echo " ]"

# Another way to print arr values
declare -p arr
```

To write the array values in a python file, you may try this :

```sh
dest="somefile.py"
{
    first=true
    echo -n "arr = [ "
    for v in "${arr[@]}" ; do
        if $first ; then first=false ; else echo -n ", " ; fi
        echo -n "\"$v\""
    done
    echo " ]"
} >| "$dest"
```

Note that it is fragile, it won't work if `v` contains `"`. A solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761032/1788851) with operator `@Q` (search Parameter transformation" in `man bash`):

```sh
dest="somefile.py"
{
    first=true
    echo -n "arr = [ "
    for v in "${arr[@]}" ; do
        if $first ; then first=false ; else echo -n ", " ; fi
        echo -n "${v@Q}"    # operator @Q
    done
    echo " ]"
} >| "$dest"
```

Comment: Hi @Thiel, how to write array so that it will appear VARIABLE_VALUE=['some value1','some value2','some value3'] format in .env file. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @swarna I have added a snippet for that; you may update the original question.

Comment: `echo -n` works fine in Bash, but the preferred and recommended solution is really to use `printf` which is coincidentally also portable.

Comment: @treplee echo is simpler to use

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues here, starting from your expected output. The command `echo ${arr}` suffers from [broken quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and only prints the first element of the array anyway; the output you expect looks like how e.g. Python represents a list, but Bash would simply print the values themselves in whichever format you specify, without any explicit formatting you didn't put there yourself.

To print an array, try

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

To print an array with explicit formatting around each value, try e.g.

```sh
printf "['%s'" "${arr[0]}"
printf ",'%s'" "${arr[@]:1}"
printf ']\n'
```

Now, to build the array properly in the first place, you have to add to the array, not to the first element.

```sh
arr=()
while true;  # not while [ ]
do 
  ........
  arr+=('some value')  # use parentheses
done
```

To add `VARIABLE_VALUE=` before the output, just ... do that.

```sh
printf "VARIABLE_VALUE=['%s'" "${arr[0]}"
printf ",'%s'" "${arr[@]:1}"
printf ']\n'
```

Comment: Hi @triplee, how to write array so that it will appear **VARIABLE_VALUES=['some value1','some value2','some value3']** format in .env file. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you already figured out that part.  In brief, `VARIABLE_VALUES=('some value1' 'some value2' 'some value3')` and then use the code in this answer, obviously replacing `arr` with `VARIABLE_VALUES`. (Though you'll generally want to [avoid upper case for your private variables.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Unless this `.env` file is consumed by Python, the format you say you want is probably not going to work. If it's going to be consumed by a Bourne shell (not Bash) you simply do not have access to array variables.

Comment: This smacks of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway. Probably (accept this answer, or post one of your own and accept that instead if you prefer, and) ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements if the problem you are trying to solve is actually different.