# sed is replacing matched text with output of another command, but that command's output contains expansion characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to replace text in a file with the output of another command.  Unfortunately, the outputted text contains characters bash expands.  For example, I'm running the following script to change the file (somestring references output that would break the sed command):

```
#!/bin/bash
somestring='$6$sPnfj/lnXwZVrec7$fCnL9uy1oWIMZduInKTHBAxhsQxGCsBpm2XfVFFqDPHKidrd93yfjbYvKgYexXHVcvkKdu9lbfy16Ek5GvKy/1'

sed '0,/^title/s/^title*/'"$somestring"'\n&/' $HOME/example.txt
```

sed fails with this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
```

I think bash is substuting the contents of $somestring when building the sed command, but is then trying to expand the resulting text.  I can't put the entire sed script in single quotes, I need bash to expand it the first time, just not the second.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: Was `somestring='$6$sPnfj/lnXwZVrec7$fCnL9uy1oWIMZduInKTHBAxhsQxGCsBpm2XfVFFqDPHKidrd93yfjbYvKgYexXHVcvkKdu9lbfy16Ek5GvKy/1'` REALLY the briefest example you could come up with to reproduce the problem? Anyway.... you may be trying to use the wrong tool but if you're stuck on sed then see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001.

Answer (score 2):

here the forward slash `/` is the problem.  If it's the only issue you can set `sed` to use a different delimiter.

for example

```
$ somestring="abc/def"; echo xxx | sed 's/xxx/'"$somestring"'/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

$ somestring="abc/def"; echo xxx | sed 's_xxx_'"$somestring"'_'
abc/def
```

you also need to worry about `&` and `\` chars and escape them if can appear in the replacement text.

If you can't control the the replacement string, either you have to sanitize with another sed script or, alternatively use `r` command to read it from a file.  For example,

```
$ seq 5 | sed -e '/3/{r replace' -e 'd}'
1
2
3slashes///1ampersand&and2backslashes\\end
4
5
```

where

```
$ cat replace
3slashes///1ampersand&and2backslashes\\end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized you change delimiter with sed.  the somestring variable holds the output from a command named grub-crypt.  Its generated at run time,  how can I escape the entire string, I won't know what text will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors here:

- the string `somestring` has characters that are significative for sed command (the most important being '/' that you are using as a delimiter)  You can escape it, by substituting it with a previous

  `somestring=$(echo "$somestring" | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g')`

  that will convert your `/` chars to `\/` sequences.
- you are using `sed '0,/^title/s/^title*/'"$somestring"'\n&/' $HOME/example.txt` which is looking to substitute the string `titl` followed by any number of `e` characters by that `$somestring` value, followed by a new line and the original one.  Unfortunately, `sed(1)` doesn't allow you to use newline characters in the pattern substitution side of the `s` command, but you can afford the result by using the `i` command with a text consisting of you pattern (preceding any new line by a `\` to interpret it as literal):

Finally the script leads to:

```
#!/bin/bash
somestring='$6$sPnfj/lnXwZVrec7$fCnL9uy1oWIMZduInKTHBAxhsQxGCsBpm2XfVFFqDPHKidrd93yfjbYvKgYexXHVcvkKdu9lbfy16Ek5GvKy/1'
somestring=$(echo "$somestring" | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g')
sed '/^title/i\
'"$somestring\\
" $HOME/example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is Bash, you can use parameter substitution to replace the problematic `/`:

```
somestring="{somestring//\//\\/}"
```

That looks scary, but is easier to understand if you look at the version that replaces `x` with `__`:

```
somestring="${somestring//x/__}"
```

---

It might be easier to use (say) underscore as the delimiter for your sed `s` command, and then the substitution above would be

```
somestring="${somestring//_/\\_}"
```

---

If you already have backslashes, you'll need to first replace those:

```
somestring="${somestring//\\/\\\\}"
somestring="{somestring//\//\\/}"
```

If there were other characters that needed escaping (e.g. on the search side of `s///`), then you could extend the above appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

This URL provides the cleanest answer:

[Command to escape a string in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854655/command-to-escape-a-string-in-bash)

```
printf "%q" "$someVariable"
```

will escape any characters you need escaped for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scaping needed is not for `bash(1)`, but for `sed(1)` command.