# Replace substring of a line with a given string

Tags: bash

I am trying to replace name with a different name, which works but when I have "[]" it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
firstString="I love [Candy] Store"
firstChange="[Candy] Store"
secondString="Chocolate Store"
echo "${firstString//$firstChange/$secondString}"
```

I am expecting:

```
"I love Chocolate Store".
```

Working example:

```
#!/bin/bash
firstString="I love Candy Store"
firstChange="Candy Store"
secondString="Chocolate Store"
echo "${firstString//$firstChange/$secondString}"
```

Output:

```
I love Chocolate Store.
```

I am trying to make it work for both the cases.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
firstString="I love [Candy] Store"
firstChange="\[Candy\] Store"
secondString="Chocolate Store"
echo "${firstString//$firstChange/$secondString}"
```

It may not help you much; if your "change" string is input from somewhere you can't count on it being properly escaped.

The problem is that the bash expansion is treating the firstChange value as a pattern not a regular string.

Per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856010/200136 , printf "%q" is the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
firstString="I love [Candy] Store"
firstChange="[Candy] Store"
printf -v quoteChange "%q\n" $firstChange
safeChange=$(echo $quoteChange)
secondString="Chocolate Store"
echo "${firstString//$safeChange/$secondString}"
```

Comment: umm.. [Candy] Store is passed as a string, so I don't think I can modify it as you mentioned above

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "may not help you much".  Edited to include a solution that might be more general

Comment: I was able to solve it by doing:
echo "${firstString//"$firstChange"/$secondString}"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I got the idea from your solution :)