# How To Make Dev C++ on wine (Ubuntu) automatically launches after compile

Tags: c, ubuntu, dev-c++, wine

I want to try some C libraries that are only available in windows so i installed wine and install dev C++.

[image]

Unlike on windows, after i compile and run, it successfuly generate/compile into "exe" but the cmd is not showing up .

[image]

I found a way on how to run the exe by launching the terminal and putting

$wine cmd
$myc.exe
[image]

It works but it takes time to manually launch the "exe".

How can i make dev c++ to automatically find cmd in wine and execute the compiled code?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE :

The time I posted this question, I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu that's why I'm looking/expecting for that functionality in wine. But now after 2 years amany months i figured out that codeblock running on wine which is for windows and cannot call ubuntu terminal once compiled.

Comment: OT: Regarding: `printf( "Hello World!" );`  This will output the text to the `stdout` I/O output stream, but will not pass it on to the terminal.  (exiting the program will flush the `stdout` s`printf( "Hello World!" );`tream to the terminal.  Suggest: `printf( "Hello World!\n" );` as the '\n' will cause the I/O stream `stdout` to be flushed to the terminal immediately

Comment: one of the buttons under dev C++ (and I think it is the `execute` button) will run the program

Comment: OT: suggest using the `project` button to create a unique directory that hold all your project sub directories, move the source code to an appropriate sub directory and work the project from there, so your desktop is not cluttered with lots of source and executable files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev-C++, by default, relies on a simple file called `ConsolePauser.exe`. This file calls the compiled `.exe` file, and gives the familiar `Process exited after 0.xxxxx seconds with return value x.` notice after it exits.

However, `ConsolePauser.exe` is a native Windows binary, it cannot be executed in Ubuntu, unless called by Wine. Also, the `ConsolePauser` calls the bare name of the executable, instead of a call to Wine, which is required.

Therefore, what you need to do to make Dev-C++ to run `.exe` files automatically after you press `F9` is to build your OWN ConsolePauser. This is quite simple, actually:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int agrc, char ** argv)
{
    using namespace std;
    string s = argv[1];
    string s1;
    for (const auto & ss : s)
    {
        if ((ss == ' ') || (ss == '\\')) s1.push_back('\\');
        s1.push_back(ss);
    }
    s = "wine " + s1;
    auto begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto retVal = system(s.c_str());
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Process completed after " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
    cout << " milliseconds with return value " << retVal << "." << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to continue. . ." << endl;
    
    cin.get();
    
    return 0;
}
```

What it simply does is parsing the argument, escaping required characters, and pass it to Wine. It is a quick and dirty version, you start improving it by checking if `argc == 1`.
Compile it as `ConsolePauser.exe` with **Ubuntu's** compiler, put it anywhere in your computer's `PATH` and it should work.

Another problem exists, however. For unknown reasons, Ubuntu's executables don't get executed in a separate window, if called by an app like Dev-C++, unlike Windows. Therefore, you will have to find a way to bring the `ConsolePauser.exe` to a new window.

A simple approach is rename your file to `ConsolePauser1.exe`, and use this code for `ConsolePauser.exe`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string s = argv[1];
    //Opens new window through gnome-terminal:
    string command = "gnome-terminal -e ";
    command += string("\"") + "bash -c ";
    command += string("\\\"") + "ConsolePauser1.exe ";
    command += string("\\\\\\\"") + s;
    command += string("\\\\\\\"");
    command += string("\\\"");
    command += string("\"");
    system(command.c_str());
    cerr << command << endl;
    
    //Make sure that window lingers...
    system("exec bash");
    return 0;
}
```

Put these two files in the same folder in your `PATH`, and the familiar old Console Pauser will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to submit my approach, although it is not specific to Ubuntu. It can work with any distro with xterm installed.
Rename `ConsolePauser.exe` to `ConsolePauserEngine.exe` and create a new `ConsolePauser.exe` text file in the same dir with the following lines:

```
#! /bin/sh

CMD=$(printf "%q" $@)   #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854655/command-to-escape-a-string-in-bash#answer-2856010
CONSOLE_PAUSER_PATH=$(printf "%q" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\ConsolePauserEngine.exe")

xterm -e "wine $CONSOLE_PAUSER_PATH $CMD"
```

EDIT: Don't forget to make the new `ConsolePauser.exe` executable.